# Can I compile ffmpeg using cygwin so that I would get redistributable dll's of it?

Tags: windows, gcc, ffmpeg, cygwin

So my point is to compile ffmpeg (I know that autobuild tools or minGW can be used but I want cygwin) using gcc to have a library (like .dll or, better .lib) usable from my windows visual studio C++ appication. Is it possible and what are main instructions on how to do such thing?

Comment: Why does your ffmpeg library need to be linked against Cygwin? I see you're using Visual Studio in your main project... I can't see the scenario where you need Cygwin functionality. Are you sure you understand what Cygwin vs MSYS/MinGW means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem a bit confused about the difference between MinGW and cygwin, but reading the following links will probably not be a waste of time:

- http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/dll.html
- http://www.emmestech.com/moron_guides/moron2.html
- http://www.mingw.org/wiki/FAQ